# Is it possible to format the tuples aligned by arrows in IntellIJ for scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting

In PyCharm there is an option to **align dict items on colon for Python**:

```
dct = {
    'one'  : 1,
    'two'  : 2,
    'three': 3,
}
```

And I want a similar way to **format the dict items on arrow for Scala in IntellIJ**:

```
val map = Map(
    "one" -> 1,
    "two" -> 2,
    "three" -> 3
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) from [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/). It can be integrated with many IDEs such us [Intellij](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#intellij) and [Visual Studio Code](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#vs-code).

Also there is an [sbt plugin for scalameta](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#sbt) that lets format the code or validate if the code is formatted (good for CI/CD)